# Do data lookup within a tfvars file

Tags: terraform

I have a module which I import values from a tfvars file into; one of the values is an SSL arn (this is usually retrieved via a data lookup) this is failing with the following error (I suspect it's taking the value literally rather than doing the actual look): `Error: module.elb_instance.aws_elb.this: "listener.0.ssl_certificate_id" (${data.aws_iam_server_certificate.ssl.arn}) is an invalid ARN: arn: invalid prefix`.

Some example of the code below (this is in the .tfvars file):

```
listeners = [
  {
     instance_port = 443
     instance_protocol = "https"
     lb_port = 443
     lb_protocol = "https"
     ssl_certificate_id = "${data.aws_iam_server_certificate.ssl.arn}"
  }
]
```

This is the data call:

```
data "aws_iam_server_certificate" "ssl" {
  name_prefix = "my.local.sslcert.example.com"
  latest      = true
}
```

and finally the relevant bits of the module:

```
locals {
  listeners = "${local.env_lists["listeners"]}"
}
module "my_elb" {
  source                    = "../modules/lb"
  listener     = "${local.listeners}"
}
```

Comment: Can you show the module that uses `listener` as well? Nothing gets interpolated in tfvars. Can the module be modified if required?

Comment: Module is this one: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/ryanuber/elb/aws/1.0.1 I'd rather not change it at all possible.